# ¿Cómo puedo limitar las columnas que se ven en una tabla creada con Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

A ver me explico, en el programa todo funciona bien, me aparecen los datos, las columnas que son 8, le coloque 2 scrollbar uno vertical y otro horizontal, estos funcionan correctamente. Pero, la tabla al tener tantas columnas se extiende demasiado cubriendo mas de lo que quiero en la ventana.
quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de limitar las columnas visibles, o controlar el ancho del Treeview.

este es el código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.resizable(1,1)
width = 1350
height= 500
window.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")

tree = ttk.Treeview(window,height=3,columns=("#1","#2","#3","#4","#5","#6")) # definir cuantas columnas tendra la tabla
tree.place(x=10,y=20) # posicion

# se le da titulo a cada una de las columnas
tree.heading("#0",text= "CODE",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#1",text= "PRODUCT",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#2",text= "PROVIDER",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#3",text= "KIND",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#4",text= "PRICE",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#5",text= "QUANTITY",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#6",text= "DESCRIPTION",anchor= "center")

# se configura cada columna
tree.column("#0", minwidth=100, width=150, stretch= False)
tree.column("#1", minwidth=150, width=200, stretch= False)
tree.column("#2", minwidth=150, width=200, stretch= False)
tree.column("#3", minwidth=150, width=200, stretch= False)
tree.column("#4", minwidth=100, width=150, stretch= False)
tree.column("#5", minwidth=100, width=150, stretch= False)
tree.column("#6", minwidth=300, width=300, stretch= False)

# para definir la scrollbar vertical
scroll_databaseV = Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
scroll_databaseV.place(x=10, y=20, height=100)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_databaseV.set)

#para definir la scrollbar hortizontal
scroll_databaseH = Scrollbar(window, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
scroll_databaseH.place(x=10, y=107, width=700)
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_databaseH.set)

#introducir los datos en el treeview
tree.insert("", END, text="CODIGO01", values=("PRODUCTO1", "PROCEDOR1", "KIND1", 200, 100, "DESCRIPCION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODIGO02", values=("PRODUCTO2", "PROCEDOR2", "KIND2", 200, 100, "DESCRIPCION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODIGO03", values=("PRODUCTO3", "PROCEDOR3", "KIND3", 200, 100, "DESCRIPCION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODIGO04", values=("PRODUCTO4", "PROCEDOR4", "KIND4", 200, 100, "DESCRIPCION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODIGO05", values=("PRODUCTO5", "PROCEDOR5", "KIND5", 200, 100, "DESCRIPCION"))


window.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, quisiera que el Treeview solo llegue al final del scrollbar que esta en posición horizontal. agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes especificar el ancho del treeview en el comando place, exactamente donde ubicas el treeview en la ventana.
Simplemente dile al comando place que quieres que el treeview tenga el mismo ancho que la barra de desplazamiento horizontal.

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(window,height=3,columns=("#1","#2","#3","#4","#5","#6")) # definir cuantas columnas tendra la tabla
tree.place(x=10,y=20, width=700) # le digo que el treeview tenga el mismo ancho que el scrollbar horizontal
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!!!!